# PyMongo: group with 2d geospatial index in conditions returns an error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The error returned is:
exception: manual matcher config not allowed

Here's my code:

```
cond = {'id': id, 'date': {'$gte': start_date}, 'date': {'$lte': end_date}, 'location': {'$within': {'$box': box }}}
reduce = 'function(obj, prev) { prev.count++; }'
rows = collection.group({'location': True}, cond, {'count': 0}, reduce)
```

When I remove location from condition then it works fine. If I change the query to `find` it works fine too so it's a problem with group.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB currently (version 1.6.2) doesn't support geo queries for mapreduce and group functions. See http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1742 for the issue ticket (and consider voting it up).